# Cant play MPMoviePlayerController and record via AVAudioRecorder at the same time?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiorecorder

I am trying to play a video in a small area of the screen and record the user's singing at the same time. however it seems the recording is not successful. 
i have added some code for you to point out possible blunders.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMedium],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM],
                                AVFormatIDKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error = nil;
[audioRecorder setDelegate:self];

audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                 initWithURL:soundFileURL
                 settings:recordSettings
                 error:&error];


if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

} else {
    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
}


[self initialiseVideo];
}


- (void) initialiseVideo
{
[audioRecorder record];

NSString *videoName = @"Medium";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:videoName ofType:@"mp4"];

if (path) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] ;
    moviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];


    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    [[moviePlayer view] setFrame:CGRectMake(58, 166, 197, 124)];
}
[moviePlayer play];

}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MPMoviePlayerController Delegate
#pragma mark -


- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
[submitButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[audioRecorder stop] ;
[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];

}


- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *) aRecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

NSLog (@"audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:successfully:");
NSLog(@"%@", aRecorder.url);
NSLog(@"%@", aRecorder.description);
// your actions here

}
-(void)audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder
                              error:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Encode Error occurred");
}



-(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender
{
if (!audioPlayer.playing)
{
    if (audioPlayer)
            [audioPlayer release];
        NSError *error;

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                       initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url
                       error:&error];

        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@",
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [audioPlayer play];
}
else
{



}
}


#pragma  mark -AV delegate methods

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

}
-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Decode Error occurred");
}
```

I hope this makes sense. The flow does not seem to enter

```
audioRecorderDidFinishRecording
```

even after

[audioRecorder stop];

please help. I am searching for this since last 3 days. but no luck :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad{

NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"KARAOKE neele neele ambar pe Karaoke With Lyrics.mp4" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200);
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];


NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];
```

}

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPlayClicked:(id)sender{
if (player.playing) {
    [player stop];
}

[moviePlayer play];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

if (!recorder.recording) {
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];

    // Start recording
    [recorder record];        
}
```

}

```
-(IBAction)ButtonStopClicked:(id)sender{
[moviePlayer stop];
[recorder stop];
if(player)
[player stop];
}

- (void) playbackStateChanged {
MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = moviePlayer.playbackState;
if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped");
    [recorder stop];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];

} else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying");
    [recorder record];
} else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused");
    [recorder pause];
} else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted");
} else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward");
} else if(playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward) {
    NSLog(@"MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward");
}
}

-(IBAction)ButtonRecordPlayClicked:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"%@",recorder.url);

if (!recorder.recording){
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
    [player setDelegate:self];
    [player setVolume:10.0];
    [player play];
}

MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *array_mp3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];

for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery)
{
    NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle]];
    if(title)
    {
        if(![array_mp3 containsObject:title])
            [array_mp3 addObject:title];
    }
}
 MPMediaItem *nowPlayingMediaItem = [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
NSURL* songURL = [nowPlayingMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVAsset* songAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:songURL options:nil];
NSString* lyrics = [songAsset lyrics];
NSLog(@"%@",lyrics);
 }

 - (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done" message: @"Finish playing the recording!"delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

It think it ll helps you.

Comment: Yes, This works, but apparently it also records the audio from the video while the headphones are plugged in. Not just the microphone recordings.

Comment: Thanks mate.. You have solved my case which took atleast 2 days badly.. I wish I could you upvotes more.